# jPOS-EE Client, Server simulator using Eclipse EE

Tags: java, eclipse, jpos

I am trying to compile and run jPOS-EE Client and Server simulators in Eclipse EE, which goes successful, as mentioned in [this](http://extendit.us/more-on-jpos-jposee-client-and-server-simulators/comment-page-1/) link. But client simulator only connects to the IP/port and does not send ISO messages. Following logs:

> [java]   
>        [java]     deploy: C:\workspac\jPos\trunk\build\deploy\30_clientsimulator.xml
>        [java]     
>        [java]     javax.management.ReflectionException: The MBean class could not be loaded
>        [java]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanInstantiator.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanInstantiator.findClass(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanInstantiator.findClass(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanInstantiator.instantiate(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanInstantiator.instantiate(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.instantiate(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at org.jpos.q2.QFactory.instantiate(QFactory.java:79)
>        [java]     at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:479)
>        [java]     at org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:294)
>        [java]     at org.jpos.q2.Q2.run(Q2.java:186)
>        [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>        [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jpos.simulator.TestRunner
>        [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>        [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>        [java]     ... 11 more
>        [java]     
>        [java]   
>        [java]

points out that MBean class is causing an error.

Can someone guide me how to compile and run jPOS modules on Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jPOS-EE has moved from GoogleCode to Github (https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE).

I suggest you take a look at the following documents:

http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf (as mentioned in http://jpos.org/learn)

and

http://jpos.org/doc/jPOS-EE.pdf

Then grab a jPOS-template (https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-template) and add the clientsimulator and serversimulator as dependencies.

Here is a recent article (http://jpos.org/blog/2015/06/replicatedspace-10-years-later/) about doing that process for another module (rspace), but the instructions are the same for client and server simulator.